# Why does hue-rotate(180deg) not work with material icons

Tags: html, css, material-design

```css
#inverted{
    filter:hue-rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(180deg);
    -moz-filter:hue-rotate(180deg);
    -ms-filter:hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
<a class="material-icons">settings</a>
<a class="material-icons" id="inverted">settings</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code i used settings icon of material-icons two times. For the 1st settings icon i did'nt used any styling. For the 2nd settings icon i set the css filter property to hue-rotate(180deg). But hue-rotate(180deg) did'nt had any effect on it. I know that to have the same effect of `filter:hue-rotate(180deg)` i can do `color:white;background-color:black`. But I want to know why hue-rotate(180deg) did'nt inverted the colors of the icon? Is there any other way of inverting colors that works with white and black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `hue-rotate` does work but `black` & `white` are not colors on the color wheel.

```css
#inverted {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}

.material-icons {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <a class="material-icons">settings</a>
  <a class="material-icons" id="inverted">settings</a>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to change white  ==> black (or vice versa) you need `filter:invert(100%)`

See: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)